# Implication of a third observer in time dilation derivation

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, thought-experiment

View from A
[image]

View from B
[image]

View from C
[image]

In the familiar experiment to derive time dilation we have observer A traveling with a light clock. The light clock sends a light pulse from the roof of the spaceship bouncing it off a mirror on the floor (one tick event). A observes the light pulse moving through twice the height D of the spaceship.

Observer B is outside to the right of the spaceship and stationary. B observes the pulse moving through 2S, where S is the square root of the sum of squares of D and L, where L is the distance the spaceship travels while the pulse moves through D. A and B measures different times for the  event because of time dilation in the different reference frames.

Observer C is situated in line and at rest with B but "above" the spaceship. C and B have synchronized their clocks and agreed on a reference frame. C observes the pulse moving through distance 2L and measures a different time than B. However B and C are in the same reference frame, how can they observe different values for time dilation of the same event?

Answer (score 4):

If Observer C does not observe the distance the light moves away from her, then she will see the light pulse moving slower by a factor of $\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle from horizontal that Observer B observes the light pulse moves in his reference frame. So, A and B will observe the light pulse to take the same amount of time.

If you object by saying that Observer C should measure the light pulse to travel at the speed of light, I would say that you are defining Observer C to ignore part of the light pulse's velocity: the part parallel to Observer C's line of sight. If the train was not moving, Observer B and Observer A would see the light pulse travel a distance of 2D. Observer C would see a travel distance of zero, and thus a speed of light of zero.

Answer (score 0):

> Observer C is situated in line with B but "above" the spaceship. C and B have synchronized their clocks and agreed on a reference frame.

This statement is not clear. If you are saying that C is at rest with respect to B then it will also observe the same time as done by B. If you are saying that B is at rest with respect to A then it will measure the same time as A. If B is at rest wrt A then it is not possible to synchronize clocks of B with clocks in frame A.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe is exactly the standard situation considered in the original light clock in a train.

When you read observer in special relativity it is generally short hand for reference frame because we are assuming that the observer is intelligent/skilled enough to account for the finite speed of light and the fact things can travel towards/away from them. Because of this your observers B and C are no different (since they agree on reference frames).

This definition of observer makes sense when you realise special relativity is a geometric theory rather then a dynamical one. I.e. it is much more natural to think of a world line in 4 dimensions and no evolution than to think of a 3D space with evolution/dynamics when we talk about special relativity. There isn't much insight you can get by thinking about exactly what a person/observer would see, but there is insight when you think about what an intelligent person with the data could determine to have happened, and this is what did happen in a particular coordinate set/reference frame.

Answer (score 0):

[Does time really dilate as explained and verified by the scientists of modern physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591643/does-time-really-dilate-as-explained-and-verified-by-the-scientists-of-modern-ph)

Sorry to say but "Time Dilation" is not real according to light clocks shown in the aforementioned question.

Addendum: There are lots to say but all the three sides of the triangle should be taken in dilated time, not just one, the hypotenuse of the right-angled triangle in the derivation of the equation of time dilation.

The distance or the base of the triangle that is used for the derivation of time dilation is not a distance covered by the lower or upper mirror in dilated time.

This real distance (S = v x t) in space is measured in real time t (not in dilated time) by the observer at rest on an asteroid who oversees the light clock moving at very high speed.

It is impossible to construct a closed triangle if all distances (3 sides) are taken in dilated time.