# Does time really dilate as explained and verified by the scientists of modern physics?

Tags: time-dilation

There is no standard light clock. Anyone can design a light clock of his/her own choice. This means it can be normal, contracted, and dilated as well but of no meaning. Some of the clocks are shown in the figure. The one with theta = 45 degrees is an anti-time dilation light clock.

https://i.postimg.cc/fWYVpF2v/IMG-2190.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Light clocks are not meaningless. All clocks do indeed slow down in fast-moving frames of reference; a fact which has been experimentally verified in numerous experiments over the years and is in complete accord with predictions based on Einstein's formulation of special relativity.